# JupyterLabを起動した直後にフリーズする

Tags: docker, jupyter-lab

Docker内にあるJupyterサーバーにブラウザから`localhost:8888`でアクセスした直後に応答がなくなります。
ログを確認してみると、以下のように表示されました。jupyterが動かなくなったのは今回が初めてなため、何をどうしたらいいのかが見当がつきません。どなたか力を貸していただけないでしょうか。

試したこと

- サーバーの再起動
- docker stop <コンテナ名>　から　docker start <コンテナ名>
- docker rm <コンテナ名>　から docker run

環境
ubuntu 18.04
Docker: kaggle
https://github.com/Kaggle/docker-python

以下ログのエラーメッセージ

```
[I 12:31:04.116 LabApp] 302 GET / (172.17.0.1) 1.220000ms
[E 12:31:05.791 LabApp] Uncaught exception GET /aipn/v1/details?1629289863635 (172.17.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/aipn/v1/details?1629289863635', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='172.17.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/caip_notebooks_serverextension/hwconfig/handlers.py", line 176, in get
        metadata = await get_metadata()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/caip_notebooks_serverextension/hwconfig/handlers.py", line 62, in get_metadata
        response = await client.fetch(request)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/simple_httpclient.py", line 344, in run
        source_ip=source_ip,
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpclient.py", line 265, in connect
        addrinfo = await self.resolver.resolve(host, port, af)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 399, in resolve
        None, _resolve_addr, host, port, family
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 382, in _resolve_addr
        addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
        for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
[W 12:31:05.792 LabApp] Unhandled error
[E 12:31:05.792 LabApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"92\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"92\"",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|51cc73ff|4625c9b03ce51fa6eadf9401fbfb0be8|1629206114",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab?",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
      "Cookie": "csrftoken=tD6NNBDQUFxyDYYkKYnr9z3D8h46juZ6vGblCudPuBbK3tbnVzUGey77UXAdNaqq; _xsrf=2|51cc73ff|4625c9b03ce51fa6eadf9401fbfb0be8|1629206114"
    }
[E 12:31:05.792 LabApp] 500 GET /aipn/v1/details?1629289863635 (172.17.0.1) 27.590000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab?
[I 12:31:06.710 LabApp] Build is up to date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
原因はgitが大量の画像データを管理しようといていたことでした。

.gitignoreで画像データを管理対象外にしたつもりが、管理対象になっていました。

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

このコマンドでgitの管理対象を調べたところ、大量の画像データが出力され、必要ないものであったため、画像を削除したところ、Jupyterがフリーズせずに動くようになりました。